# Error while making the RPC call: TypeError: this.do_action is not a function

Tags: rpc, odoo-16

Error while making the RPC call: TypeError: this.do_action is not a function when i try to open record it gives me this error.

```
odoo.define('ecare_medical_history.EditPatientProfile', function (require) {
    "use strict";
            self = this;
            var rpc = require('web.rpc');
            var AbstractAction = require('web.AbstractAction');
            var servicesMixin = require('web.ServicesMixin');
            var core = require('web.core');
    
            $(document).on('click', '.editPatientProfile', async function() {
    
                try {
                    var result = await rpc.query({
                        model: 'ec.patient.timeline',
                        method: 'action_open_patient_time_view',
                        args: [],
                    });
    
                    alert("test");
                    console.log(result);
    
                    // Check if the result is valid before calling do_action
                    if (result) {
                        return await this.do_action(result);
                    } else {
                        console.error('RPC call did not return a valid result.');
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error while making the RPC call:', error);
                }
            });
    
    
    
    
    });
```

Error while making the RPC call: TypeError: this.do_action is not a function when i try to open record it gives me this error.